# < character in RichTextBox causing issues

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

EDIT - Sorry folks, i guess i wanted to "obscure" my work code too much... i don't know why it got so many downvotes but anyway. see below for update/edit with actual code.

I am trying to insert a piece of text into an existing section of a line (`<data)` which resides at the beginning of a line in my RichTextBox control. However, whenever i do that in the following manner:

```
private void AddSelectedIntellisense(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripItem x = sender as ToolStripItem;
        int cursorpos = this.txt_Body.SelectionStart;
        string final = this.txt_Body.Text.Insert(cursorpos, x.Text);
            //final var at breakpoint is equal to "<data log=\"Original\""
            //then i assign it/that to the RTB.Text
        this.txt_Body.Text = final;
            //when checked with breakpoint, this.txt_Body.Text is equal to
            //"log=\"\"<data log=\"Original\"" 
        this.txt_Body.SelectionStart = cursorpos + x.Text.Length;
    }
```

I am thinking that it is the < character that is causing issues when i assign the string to the .Text property (because if i replace the < with a [ in my logic, no problems), but i don't know how to fix it... if you could help me i would really appreciate it.

I also checked all of the indexes manually and they all lign up perfectly... so i don't know why the RTB.Text value is different than the string but if someone knows please tell me.

Cheers!

Comment: What is this language `(txt = "...")` surely not C#

Comment: I think he meant those as comments.  Editing...

Comment: they were... thanks Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are first setting:

```
txt = this.RTB1.Text.Substring(starts, length);
```

Then on the next line you are replacing the value of txt:

```
txt = this.RTB1.Text.Insert(index,"log='test'></data>");
```

You are probably looking to concatenate the strings:

```
string txt = this.RTB1.Text.Substring(starts, length);
txt += this.RTB1.Text.Insert(index,"log='test'></data>");
this.RTB1.Text = txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok folks... i suppose i'll give it to Aaron, since it's like somewhat related and nobody else answered.

The answer was:
I am using the RTB.On_TextChanged event to fire off the intellisense based on a condition. However, because i am also setting text the RTB.Text value within the Intellisense, the condition became true twice and added the specific text twice. So i setup a flag when i add intellisense text and check it in the on_textchanged event.

Cheers and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You don't have to pick it as the accepted answer if it wasn't the actual answer to the problem--you can even accept your own answer if you ultimately solved it yourself (and honestly not suggested by anyone's help), which seems to be the case.  However, I think he was correct about that being a "bug" in the code you originally posted, if not the larger bug you were immediately looking to solve.

Comment: Also, notice that the actual problem was in a factor which was completely omitted from the original post.  Had you mentioned that the method was triggered by the TextChanged event the recursive event trigger of assigning to Text might have been noticed.  The moral of this story is that a debugger on the full actual code is more effective than many eyeballs on too small a part of the code.  So, when you're really stumped, make sure to provide a more complete and accurate picture of the problem.  8-)

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciate your help :)